# Strange behaviour when using the Home button in GreenDroid ActionBar's

Tags: android, greendroid

I'm using GreenDroid ActionBar's component and I've two strange behaviours when I'm using the ActionBar's Home button.

I've a 3 activities:

- myMainActivity that extends GDListActivity.
- myDetailedItem that extends GDActivity, that it's showed when the user presses a list item.
- myInformation that also extends GDActivity.

The first rare thing is after click the Home button I cannot get an intent value I pass to the myDetailedItem.

The process is: myMainActivity --> myDetailedItem --> myMainActivity (use the Home button) --> myDetailedItem, but in this activity I don't recieve the intent value when using getIntent().getIntExtra("myValue",-1) that I've put in myMainActivity and it perfectly work the first time and it always works when using the back button.

The second strange thing is doing the following:
myMainActivity --> myDetailedItem --> myMainActivity (Home button) --> myInformation (button in ActionBar) --> myDetailedItem (when pressing back button) instead of going to myMainActivity

In myApplication I've:

```
@Override
public Class<?> getHomeActivityClass() {
    return myMainActivity.class;
}
```

And also tested with these two overrides:

```
@Override
public Intent getMainApplicationIntent() {
    return null; 
}
```

and:

```
@Override
public Intent getMainApplicationIntent() {
    return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT); 
}
```

How can I solve these problems? Are they related each other?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

At the end I have been able to find my mistake. I don't know why, probably copying from somewhere, I had in my *AndroidManifest* the following property in the myMainActivity:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

I have changed it for *singleTask* and now the behaviour of the Home button is correct and the intent problem is also solved.